# Set up a cron job to run drush migrate command

Tags: migrations, cron

I have a custom module which migrates articles from a [remote xml file](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2017/06/07/stop-waiting-for-feeds-module-how-to-import-remote-feeds-in-drupal-8/). Because the RSS feed changes, I want my Drupal site to be in sync with the RSS feed. How do add e.g this command `drush mim xml_content` to my cron job, so it will update by each cron interval?

Or how do I add it to my custom module with hook_cron()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's certainly possible programmatically invoke a Drush command in a custom hook handler (via `drush_invoke_process()`), you shouldn't do this.

Cron tasks are designed to handle periodic, smallish, update tasks on hourly, or sub-hourly, intervals. Migration jobs can get pretty I/O heavy so you shouldn't couple them on the same schedule as ongoing cron maintenance, lest you add potential instability based on some outside service/feed.

You should add a new cron job to your cron runner (e.g. crontab, Jenkins, etc.) that executes the `drush mim xml_content` on its own schedule. Depending on where your cron system is, the cron job will evoke `drush mim xml_content` or `drush @host-alias mim xml_content` (if your cron runner is outside the Drupal host machine).